# Mock a function that takes in a List of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mocking, tdd

I want to write a test for a method with the following signature

```
public List<CrateRecallTaskWithComms> PopulateCrateRecallTask(List<Task> listOfBaseTasks)
{
    var crateRecallTasksWithComms = new List<CrateRecallTaskWithComms>();
    foreach (var task in listOfBaseTasks)
    {
        // do stuff

        var crateRecallTasksWithComms = new CrateRecallTaskWithComms()
        {
            // populate properties
        }

        // add to list
        crateRecallTasksWithComms.Add(crateRecallTasksWithComms);
    }

    // return populated list
    return crateRecallTasksWithComms;
}
```

I am using the `Mock` library to mock this method, however I cannot get it work! Here is my test code so far:

```
_crateRecallService = new Mock<CrateRecallsService>();
_crateRecallService.Setup(m => m.PopulateCrateRecallTask(It.IsAny<List<Task>>()).Returns());
```

I am getting error at the `It.IsAny<>` bit, the error says:

> Argument type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<Zenos.Intranet.Domain.Tasks.Task>` is
>   not assignable to parameter type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<Task>`

[image: error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Task is a standard class in .Net framework.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen this before while I've been refactoring code. I was pulling my hair out, trying to fix it, and finally I figured out that I just needed to rebuild the target class. The error went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be two classes named `Task`.

I think your method expects a list of `System.Task`, but you're setting it up with a list of `Zenos.Intranet.Domain.Tasks.Task`. You're probably missing a `using` directive to disambiguate between the two types..